# Getting SSO user's id or name from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, apache, single-sign-on

I'm hosting a small portal application using Apache with SSO - is there any way to display (like: present on the web page) user's SSO login/name once they are authenticated and using the portal page? Authentication uses MS Active Directory.

Comment: Are you getting a SAML response back? If so, how are you parsing that?

Comment: Not really - not even sure how I would do that. Apache's doing all the work, SSO-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I was able to find so far is to use PHP.

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; ?>
```

However there's gotta be a way to access the same information from JS...